# How to convert Data Frame to user defined format

Tags: python, pandas

i have a csv file

```
Row,employee_region,employee_branch,NAME,employee_email,employee_mobile_number,employee_nationality,employee_salary,employee_DOB
1        x           a              emp1       null           9986754352                 cc               25000         10/8/1982
2        x           b              emp2      emp2@bb.com     9986754352                 dc               55000         05/06/1987
3        y           c              emp3      emp3@bb.com     9886756352                 hc               85000         01/01/1980
```

Actually the number of records are more than 1000

based on salary i added one column position

```
normal = data_df['salary'] <= 25000
experienced = (data_df['salary'] > 25000) & (data_df['salary'] <= 50000)
#vip = (data_df['salary'] > 50000) & (data_df['salary'] <= 50000)
data_df['position'] = np.where(normal, 'normal', np.where(experienced, 'experienced','manager'))
```

According to the salary 3 positions are there

```
normal -----salary<=25000
experienced----salary >25000 && salary <=50000
manager--------salary>50000
```

i would like to get the result in the form mentioned below using pandas

```
employee_region    employee_branch    count_employee_email    count_employee_mobile  count_employee_DOB   %count_employee_email    %count_employee_mobile  %count_employee_dob  count_normal_employee  count_experienced_employee   count_manager
    x                    b                    1                        1                      1                  count(tuple)/totalcount(column)                                          0                      1                          0
```

Comment: I suggest you not to use regular expressions to do that. I just suggest you using databases...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reformat pandas DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425093/reformat-pandas-dataframe)